# One page website basic layout

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout for my onepage site, I've never made one before so it is very much a learning curve.

The only issue I can currently see with this is when I shrink the height of the page, the div size also shrinks, even when I add `min-height: 800px;`. What can I do to get around this issue? (If I didn't explain this properly, use my code and shrink the height of your page so you can only just see the background-colors, then scroll, you will notice that in fact, the height is not 800px),

```css
div.top,
div.mid,
div.bottom {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
div.top {
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
}
div.mid {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 100vh;
}
div.bottom {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <h1>Top</h1>
</div>

<div class="mid">
  <h1>Mid</h1>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  <h1>Bottom</h1>
</div>
```

EDIT: To explain why I am using `position: absolute`
I use `position: absolute` so that I am able to use `top` `left` and `right` so that I don't have the margin around each div.

Without `absolute`
[image]

With `absolute`
[image]

Comment: it's because of the `position:absolute;`

Comment: @GvM well what would you suggest to use instead? because `fixed` disables the ability to scroll and `relative` creates an ugly layout that I would never use

Comment: When you use `position: absolute` the element has no weight on the page, therefore the browser will render it and then won't process it again.  You are using div's stacked ontop of one another so there is no need to use an absolute position, they will naturally stack

Comment: I use `absolute` so that I can extend the edges of the divs to the very edges of the page by using `left`, `right` and `top`, otherwise there is a margin around the outside of each div which I don't like. Can you suggest another method ? And yes I have tried `margin: 0` with no success

Comment: Remove that [top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top), and position:absolute rule from your CSS, if you use the inspect tools in Chrome or Firefox, you can see that your div height is actually 800px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.top, .mid, .bot {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}
.top {
  background: red;
}
.mid {
  background: blue;
}
.bot {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="top">
   <span>top</span>
 </div>
 <div class="mid">
   <span>mid</span>
 </div>
 <div class="bot">
   <span>bot</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ah, I did not think of the default margin that body has. This works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'margin' is coming from the H1 tag, removed that and the gap disappears from between the divs. I've removed the absolute positioning and left / right / top values because they are redundant with the removal of the margin:

```css
div.top,
div.mid,
div.bottom {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

div.top {
  background-color: red;
}
div.mid {
  background-color: blue;
}
div.bottom {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <h1>Top</h1>
</div>

<div class="mid">
  <h1>Mid</h1>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  <h1>Bottom</h1>
</div>
```